# SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) when link boost-thread and boost-regex via cmake

Tags: c++, multithreading, cmake, boost-thread, mongo-cxx-driver

I try compile and run example of mongo-cxx-driver. It requires linking Boost-system, boost-thread and boost-regex. When I compile by commad line:

`g++ simple_client_demo.cpp -I/home/ssi/mongo-client-install/include -L/home/ssi/mongo-client-install/lib -lmongoclient -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_regex`

all is well. But when I try compile by Cmake, I get Signal: `SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)` in /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional(2030 line `_M_manager(_M_functor, _M_functor, __destroy_functor);` if it does matter).

Part of my CMakeList.txt, which link Boost:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(test_mongo_c_driver)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories("/home/ssi/mongo-client-install/include")
link_directories("/home/ssi/mongo-client-install/lib")
#link_directories("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
#add_library(mongoclient)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system regex)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()


set(SOURCE_FILES
    simple_client_demo.cpp
#    tutor2.cpp
    )

add_executable(test_mongo_c_driver ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test_mongo_c_driver mongoclient ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

`ldd a.out` (compile from `g++` command):

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd41b5000)
        libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f236fda7000)
        libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f236fb91000)
        libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 (0x00007f236f889000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f236f585000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f236f27f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f236f068000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f236eca3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f236ffd2000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f236ea9b000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f236e87c000)
        libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007f236e503000)
        libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007f236e0fc000)
        libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007f236c88e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f236c68a000)
```

`ldd test_mongo_c_driver` (compile from cmake):

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7163000)
        libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fc61ea28000)
        libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fc61e823000)
        libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fc61e51c000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc61e218000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc61df11000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc61dcfb000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc61d936000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc61ec65000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc61d72d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc61d50f000)
        libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007fc61d196000)
        libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007fc61cd8e000)
        libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007fc61b521000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc61b31c000)
```

This is my simple_client_demo.cpp:

```
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h" // the mongo c++ driver

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace mongo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        std::cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " [MONGODB_URI]" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    mongo::client::GlobalInstance instance;
    if (!instance.initialized())
    {
        std::cout << "failed to initialize the client driver: " << instance.status() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::string uri = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "mongodb://meowtom.ru:27017";
    std::string errmsg;

    ConnectionString cs = ConnectionString::parse(uri, errmsg);

    if (!cs.isValid())
    {
        std::cout << "Error parsing connection string " << uri << ": " << errmsg << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    boost::scoped_ptr<DBClientBase> conn(cs.connect(errmsg));
    if (!conn)
    {
        cout << "couldn't connect : " << errmsg << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    try
    {
        unsigned long long count = conn->count("test.users");
        cout << "count of exiting documents in collection test.foo : " << count << endl;

        conn->remove("test.foo", BSONObj());

        BSONObj o = BSON("hello" << "world");
        conn->insert("test.users", o);
        Query query;
        BSONObj ret = conn->findOne("test.users", query);
        std::cout << ret.toString() << '\n';
        string e = conn->getLastError();
        if (!e.empty())
        {
            cout << "insert #1 failed: " << e << endl;
        }

        // make an index with a unique key constraint
        conn->createIndex("test.foo", IndexSpec().addKeys(BSON("hello" << 1)).unique());

        try
        {
            conn->insert("test.foo", o); // will cause a dup key error on "hello" field

        }
        catch (const OperationException &)
        {
            // duplicate key error
        }
//        cout << "we expect a dup key error here:" << endl;
//        cout << "  " << conn->getLastErrorDetailed().toString() << endl;
    }
    catch (DBException &e)
    {
        cout << "caught DBException " << e.toString() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output for `make VERBOSE=1`:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -H/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver -B/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver/CMakeFiles /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver'
make -f CMakeFiles/test_mongo_c_driver.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test_mongo_c_driver.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver'
cd /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver/CMakeFiles/test_mongo_c_driver.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver'
make -f CMakeFiles/test_mongo_c_driver.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/test_mongo_c_driver.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/test_mongo_c_driver.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver/CMakeFiles  1
[100%] Built target test_mongo_c_driver
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/ssi/cppproj/test-mongo-c-driver/CMakeFiles 0
```

Comment: please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). what is the output from `ldd test_mongo_c_driver` for both the cmake and the command line compile result?

Comment: m.s., I'm sorry for the delay. I edited post.

Comment: please run `make VERBOSE=1` on the cmake build to see the actual compilation and linker flags and post it here as well; does your command line build crash if you supply `-std=c++11` as well?

Comment: And I found [similar trouble](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-562) but my case is simplest and I getting this via cmake only

Comment: m.s., yes, it crash if I build from commad line with `-std=c++11`-flag. And all is well if build via cmake without this flag. Thank you very much!

Comment: So, is cmake required to reproduce the problem or not? Also, is the mongo driver required or not? What about either Boost lib? In order to find a problem, you need to extract a minimal error case first and that includes eliminating all unnecessary elements.